# Reading ftdi to show string

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, rfid

I use this code to read the RFID chip SN through ftdi usb reader.
I want to use the RFID SN (0DBFFC21) later in SQL queries.

My problem is that I get the SN many times splited in two rows...
How should I put there a delay or something, so I can get full string everytime?

[image]

```
    #region Namespace Inclusions
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

namespace SerialPortExample
{
  class SerialPortProgram
  {
    // Create the serial port with basic settings
    private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1",
      9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
      // Instatiate this class
      new SerialPortProgram();
    }

    private SerialPortProgram()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");

      // Attach a method to be called when there
      // is data waiting in the port's buffer
      port.DataReceived += new 
        SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

      // Begin communications
      port.Open();

      // Enter an application loop to keep this thread alive
      Application.Run();
    }

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender,
      SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
      Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add to your question the expected full string? according to the screenshot you added.

Comment: does this string have a defined length? What value has `port.BytesToRead` when the `DataReceived` event is fired each time? Does it correspond to the read string?

Comment: @KernelMode, it should be `0DBFFC21` always. And the problem is well known (though can't find nice looking duplicate, perhaps [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2604932/1997232)). `SerialPort.DataReceived` is not guaranteed to be rised for complete packet (I believe unless you setup timeout and use handshake), it may come after just one byte received. You have to concatenate messages yourself.

Comment: I need to read the serial number from the rfid chips,  the i cang get from sql the employee name.  Also different chip, different serial number, can have diff lenght

Comment: @Sinatr, Thanks. So how do you know that you done reading all the SN?

Comment: I am new in c# but my idea is something like this:  read the chip -> get the value (SN) -> wait 1000ms (so i get full SN) -> run sql query

Comment: You may receive only a part if you wait too little or opposite, waiting too long will concatenated several times SN (e.g. `0DBFFC210DB`) . Do you know anything for sure? E.g. is it always 8 characters, is it sent every 1 second, etc.?

Comment: Ok can try with always 8char

Comment: Your screenshot is showing a linefeed at the end of each complete serial number.  Why don't you just buffer until you see that line feed?

Comment: we can try it with the linefeed, maybe its better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach may vary, but here is one simple to read data of known size:

```
string _buffer;

void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    _buffer += port.ReadExisting(); // read into buffer
    if (_buffer.Length > 7) // wait until at least 8 characters are received
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_buffer.Substring(0, 8)); // display
        _buffer = _buffer.Substring(8, _buffer.Length - 8); // remove from buffer
    }
}
```

if delay between packets is big enough following code may be sufficient:

```
    _buffer += port.ReadExisting();
    if (_buffer.Length >= 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_buffer);
        _buffer = null;
    }
```

Comment: @Sintar, if the data received has length of 100, why in the last line you assign to `buffer` 92 characters? What's the point of it?

Comment: i try it, but it now work correctly [see here](http://imgur.com/a/KudAl), the first is ok but second is bad ....

Comment: @KernelMode, it may happens what you read several bytes of the next packet at the moment when event occurs. If it's not the case (e.g. if there is a big delay between packets, processing is fast, etc.), then simply clear buffer instead (`_buffer = null`).

Comment: @Sinatr, you always printing the **first 8** characters and after that you cut the  **last 8** characters. Did you mean to cut the first 8?

Comment: now its on 99% fine, but sometimes (1 of 20try)  its is not in one line [se here](http://imgur.com/a/dQnwj), but i can prevent this that i check the lenght before sql query.