# C# SerialPort DataReceived problem when when attached strings

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a DataReceived method being trigger a data is send from a RS232 device. Things run smoothly with the following code

```
byte[] data = new Byte[serialPort.BytesToRead];
serialPort.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
string read = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

but if I add a string after a data

```
string read = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data) + "asdf \n";
```

The data is still received but occasionally would be displayed incorrectly. E.g. if I'm connecting to a scale and should be reading "10.45kg asdf" it would show on my computer as "10. asdf45kg".  What is the problem here?

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the devices you are using.... Since there might be different protocols for each device...and we need to send request in particular format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataReceived` method will be triggered when the serial port feels like triggering it, which is NOT necessarily when you receive a full string from the device.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299187/what-causes-the-net-serialport-class-datareceived-event-to-fire/2299217#2299217) for a great discussion of the details.  If you have a known terminator character, you can work around this problem by setting the `NewLine` property of the SerialPort, and then using `ReadLine()`.

Comment: mtrw, nice suggestion. It worked now.  My instrument (a wireless data module) includes a software which allows me configure the instrument data's EOP character. I picked "~" to be my EOP and NewLine = "~". Then the problem is solved. But what if I do not have the software. How would I add the EOP? Assuming I cannot write to the instrument to change its EOP. How would I do that from my computer?

Comment: Though problem solved, I would appreciate if someone explain me the concept behind the Newline? So DataReceived is trigger any time in between character frame? If I restricted the NewLine to be some character - before the full string is transmitted to the computer, where is the partial string hiding?

Comment: In general, the device specification tells you the End of Line/End of Packet character.  You don't (usually) get to change it.  I'd recommend you use either newline or carriage return ('\n' or '\r') for the EOL character, that's pretty common.  As for your second question, the partial string is hiding in the serial port's internal buffer, or in the associated low-level OS internal buffer.  The event is fired by the OS when it notices that there are at least some characters available to read.

Comment: I wonder why DataReceived method would not separate itself each time it is fired. (e.g. the 2nd DataReceived thread shouldn't start until the 1nd DataReceive is finished). If I don't use EOL to buffer it, they would strangely mix together. Also if I'm triggering continuously, would could I control each buffering time to be consistent - e.g. each data is separated by 50ms? If DataReceived is triggered whenever it feels like to, I can't control the length of buffer and the timing between each data received. Is there a solution (even conceptually, so I can attempt to solve it)?

Comment: Conceptually, you need to know enough about the protocol to buffer the characters, scan through the buffer, and decode complete messages.  Please read the other SO question and answer that I linked to it my original answer for more details.  By the way, when you set the NewLine character in the .NET class, .NET is doing just this for you - it scans the incoming characters, storing them internally until it sees the EOL string.  When it does, it copies the characters out of its internal buffer and makes that string available to ReadLine.