# Duplicate data received on Serial Port

Tags: c#

I am reading data from a police scanner using C# and serial ports (USB to Serial). When I view the data in a different program there's no problem. When I use the following code I get repeat (duplicate) lines for everything. What am I doing wrong?

```
SerialPort _sp = new SerialPort();
_sp.BaudRate = 115000;
_sp.DataBits = 8;
_sp.Parity = Parity.None;
_sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
```

and the function to start serial port reading...

```
public void StartSerial()
{
    _sp.PortName = comboPorts.SelectedItem.ToString();
    _sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
    _sp.Open();
}
```

and the read function...

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String strLine = _sp.ReadLine();
        // Handle Data
    }
    catch { }
}
```

The manual states the following is required:

> To view CCDump data, connect the radio to a personal computer using the USB PC/IF cable. Start a terminal program or your third party application software. Configure the communications parameters for “115200, N, 8, 1” as follows:
>
> COM Port: The COM port number assigned to the USB cable by your computer. If you are running a Windows operating system, you can find this information under “Ports” in the Device Manager.
>
> Parity: None
>
> Baud Rate: 115,000 bits per second
>
> Word: 8 bits
>
> Stop Bits: 1

Comment: can you show complete (cutdown, compilable) code that exhibits this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. The data is being sent as duplicates so there's nothing I can do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the serialPort_DataReceived event had been fired for multiple times even there is only one line of data,

Check the settings , there should be  a threshold, which means if the data length is less then the threshold , then the event won't be fired.

In the mean time,make sure you only register the event once...

Comment: What should the threshold be set to? Sample data is like "P25:T0001:80900259025A0259025AD14C" each line is that long.

Answer (score 1):

You must read whatever data is available at once. Do not use ReadLine since it's not clear which character the device uses to send LF or CR or if it even has them sent to you. Instead use this:

```
            int totalBytes = _sp.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[totalBytes];
            _sp.Read(buffer, 0, totalBytes);
```

or

```
  string line = _sp.ReadExisting();
```

Comment: I'm getting duplicate data with `_sp.ReadExisting();` the data is 

P25:T0001:160000C00055FFFF0001CC47
P25:T0001:BD001325E032091B94C412AC
P25:T0001:00900259025A0259025A3578
P25:T0001:020001870286005D00082D99
P25:T0001:89900B40000000000000D9CA
P25:T0001:05900000000000000000D1C3
P25:T0001:020001AF09F7018702866672
P25:T0001:BB0000BEE0014401B970E51E
P25:T0001:3A00001144010101B97014D9
P25:T0001:160000C00055FFFF0001CC47
P25:T0001:BD000322D0320A2510A28794
P25:T0001:009002590259025A0259B299
P25:T0001:0200005D000801AF09F7E1BC

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. The data is being sent as duplicates so there's nothing I can do.

Comment: What about the code before that reading exactly the bytes that are available? Store the first reading in a variable and then compare it to the second. `Readexisting` since it returns also string, could be using the same code as `ReadLine`. The above code is a copy/paste from a code that I'm using and it works fine. Also, make sure you have only one delegate assigned to it.

Comment: I would've used the first one but that means somewhere I would have to split out all the P25 segments. This wouldn't change my outcome because it looks like the police scanner is putting out doubles anyways (I looked at Putty's output and its the same).

Answer (score 1):

I was writing a piece of application which logged Serial data through USB and ran into similar issues where I was getting incomplete (partial) data, duplicated data, and worst, combination of both. The problem was latter solved.

The reason is that `DataReceive` does not trigger consistently, and can potentially trigger anyway it prefers if no restriction is configured. What I did was setting an **EOP Character** so application will buffer until it read the EOP and logged the complete data string only once and await for the next **EOP Char** to log the next data. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345331/c-sharp-serialport-datareceived-problem-when-when-attached-strings) for related discussion.

In my case, I attached `{CR+LF}` (i.e. a carrier return and a new line) to each end of my data string as my **EOP Char**.  Each data string, e.g. `"Hello world"`, sent will become `"Hello World{CR}{LF}"`. In my code where I set my port, baud rate and other properties I also set a `NewLine` property to match the **EOP Char** I set for my device:

```
myPort.NewLine = "\r\n";
```