# Serial port data is coming duplicated or resent (some chars)

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

Let me explain the scenario: serial port that bring me data (string) as the following example:

02051014 0009       M      0  741             30041105 2632           0    30041105

I have tried all kinds of read (read, read byte, read char, read line, read existing). I tried to change the [new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345331/c-sharp-serialport-datareceived-problem-when-when-attached-strings) but the data keeps duplicated. Look to the example above, and now look how data is coming:

0220510114 00009       M      0  741             300441105 2632           0    300411055

Anyone have any idea of how can I solve this problem?

The code:

```
[...]
try
{
    this.serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 2400, Parity.None, 7, StopBits.One);
    this.serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(portaSerial_DataReceived);
    this.serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
    this.serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    this.serialPort.Open();
}
[...]
private void portaSerial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var invalidValuesToBreakLine = new int[] { 13, 10, 0 };
        int data;

        while (this.serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            data = this.serialPort.ReadChar();

            if (invalidValuesToBreakLine.Contains(data))
            {
                if (!this.breakLineWasPerformed)
                {
                    this.breakLineWasPerformed = true;

                    this.dataList.Add(this.temporaryString);

                    this.temporaryString = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.breakLineWasPerformed)
                {
                    this.breakLineWasPerformed = false;
                }

                this.temporaryString += (char)data;
            }
        }
[...]
```

Comment: Have you got the BAUD, Parity etc all set up correctly? Could be problems with the connection and a resend attempted?

Comment: I don't see duplicate data.  You do understand how serial data is transmited right?  **Post your code.**

Comment: @Ramhound: Care to explain a bit further why the doubled `2` and the doubled `5` at the end of the string are normal?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - Clearly the value the author is getting is wrong, and its not normal, but its not duplicated data. More then a single byte is being resent for a reason. I suspect the code that handles how the bytes are read. **Since I highly suspect you know the answer I will let you answer your own question.**  I am tired of people downvoting my answers within this community after I provide feedback to my own downvote.

Comment: @Ramhound: I see, I though you didn't see the additional 2 and 5 in the message :-D

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - Besides the fact there are more then just the additional `2` and `5` in the message?

Comment: @Belogix - yes, baud, parity and etc is correct.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ha, great, I didn't see those :-)

Comment: How do you "get" this data? Does it just pump this data out? I.e. could you use a basic RS232 application to get the data and check if that also has the data errors?

Comment: @Ramhound I put the code now.

Comment: @Belogix I use another app, and is not duplicated.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni - Your code is incomplete.

Comment: @Vinicius Ottoni - You said in your post with Belogix that you tested the incoming serial data with a simple receiver from codeproject and having the same corrupted result. This indicates either the data is already corrupted at source or something is wrong with the transfer protocol settings. Serial communication using "2400,N,7,1" is not very  common, the most common setting for commercial product is 2400,N,8,1". Maybe you can try changing to 8 bits setting to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Having dug about I've found this [StackOverflow question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299187/what-causes-the-net-serialport-class-datareceived-event-to-fire/2299217#2299217) that suggests the `DataReceived` event can fire off at unexpected times. So, if possible you should set a `NewLine` and trigger on that.

As a test of this idea you could try adding a button and wait until you **KNOW** you have some data and then click it to show you the stream. If there are no duplicates then that points to the `DataReceived` event as being over eager and firing incorrectly. You may then want to check your `NewLine`, `DtrEnable` and `DsrHolding` etc.

```
private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string indata = this.serialPort.ReadExisting();
    MessageBox.Show(indata);
}
```

Comment: Yes. "I have tried all kinds of read (read, read byte, read char, read line, read existing)"

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni - OK, I have changed my answer to try another idea and move away from using DataReceived event being reliable!

Comment: There's no way to know when the data will be avaliable. =/ So, I put a thread doing that, all time requesting if there is data avaliable, same thing, duplicated chars. =(

Comment: Sure, this was never a solution but just trying to see if it would shed some light on your problem! You say thread, does it do just as I have done here so just grabs data without being too clever?

Comment: I need to put a thread to get avaliable data all the time, because I've to update the data, it is a online system.

Comment: Have you tried a simple Windows application that has a button you can click to read the stream as I suggested. This is investigative work and NOT the final solution but you need to try what I've suggested first to see if that gets OK data. It doesn't matter that it won't be the final solution and we can work towards that. What matters now is trying what I've said, on a button click, to remove threading, events etc etc out of the way and have a very clear, very clean one button click to read what is in the buffer at that time. Once we have that we can move forward with events / threading etc.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I got this project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-and run, same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to reset `data` to an empty string after each call to the `ReadChar()` method, and or flush the input buffer.

I suspect that the call to `BytesToRead()` is returning greater than zero, yet the ReadChar() call is returning the original character on the serial port buffer. This is due to the internal timings of a serial port, and the fact that your code is likely "running too fast" for the hardware device.

I would maybe rethink the whole while loop in the method. You could probably simplify this a lot, and just try the following (with your customized code)

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Console.Write(indata);
}
```

To change your newline chars, just examine the `indata` string and break on your characters, store the result in a global variable, and then reuse the left over data.

Comment: Again... repeated characteres.

Comment: Is possible to clean the last char that I get from the buffer?